# why does my tiled tilemap return a 'not a function' error when i implement sockets into my phaser3 code?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, phaser-framework

I am creating a node server for my game so i can implement an online multiplayer mode using sockets, to test it i have been trying to get my single player mode to work on the server. i have managed to get my main menu scene to load and transfer to my single player game scene through a button. but instead of loading the tile map like it used to before adding sockets, i now get a console error saying "this.skymap.createLayer is not a function"

this is the server.js code

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
server.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

below is the code for the main menu.

```js
class mainMenu extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super('menu')
    }
preload(){
    this.load.image('mainMenu','assets/mainMenu.png')
    this.load.image('timeTrialButton','assets/timeTrialButton.png')
    this.load.image('multiPlayerButton','assets/multiPlayerButton.png')
}

create(){
    this.socket = io.connect();
    this.registry.set("socket",this.socket)
    this.add.image(640,480,'mainMenu')
    const timeTrialButton = this.add.image(100,800,'timeTrialButton').setInteractive()
    const multiPlayerButton = this.add.image(1180,800,'multiPlayerButton').setInteractive()

    timeTrialButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
        this.scene.launch('gamescene').stop()
    });

    // multiPlayerButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
    //     game.scene.add('gameScene', gameScene, true, { x: 1280, y: 960 });
    //     game.scene.remove('timeTrialEnd');
    //     console.log('loaded')
    //});
}
    
}
```

and below is the code for the single player scene of the game

```js
class gameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('gamescene')
    }

     preload(){
        this.k=0
        this.velocity = 0
        this.endReached = false
        this.facingLeft=false
        this.facingRight=false
        //load stage and tileset
        this.load.image('tiles', 'assets/skyTileset.png');
        this.load.image('goalFlag','assets/goalFlag.png')
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('sky', 'assets/bouncy_shrooms.json');
        //loading assets into game
        this.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/player.png',
        { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 }
            );

    };
     create(){
        this.socket = this.registry.get("socket",this.socket)// connecting every scene to the socket connection
        console.log('game scene loaded')
            // timer function (with help from @winner_joiner on stack overflow)
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(
        () => { 
            this.seconds = this.seconds + 1
            this.timerText.setText(this.seconds)
        },1000);
         //create assets within the game
        this.skyMap = this.make.tilemap({key: 'sky'});
        this.tileset = this.skyMap.addTilesetImage('skyShrooms','tiles');
        this.background = this.skyMap.createLayer('sky', this.tileset,);           
        this.platforms = this.skyMap.createLayer('platforms', this.tileset,);
        this.stems = this.skyMap.createLayer('stems', this.tileset,);
        this.platforms.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);
    
        this.goal = this.physics.add.sprite(1200, 87, 'goalFlag')
        this.goal.setScale(0.1)
        this.goal.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        this.goal.setImmovable(true)

        this.physics.world.setBounds(0,0,1280,960)
        //loading the player sprite as a physics based sprite.
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(50,850,"player");
        //this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(1000,50,"player");
        this.player.setScale(1.75)
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platforms);
        

        
        this.timerText = this.add.text(this.player.x+50, this.player.y-50, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#fff' });

        this.timerText.setText(0);
   
        //player animations
    
        this.anims.create({
            key: "left-idle",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', { start: 1, end: 1 }),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1

        })
        this.anims.create({
            key: "right-idle",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 0, end: 0}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"left-walk",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 6, end: 9}),
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"right-walk",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 2, end: 5}),
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"right-jump",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 10, end: 10}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"right-fall",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 11, end: 11}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"left-jump",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 12, end: 12}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"left-fall",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 13, end: 13}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        

        //camera
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
        this.cameras.main.setBounds(0,0,1280,960);
    };
```

if you need any more info please let me know.
any and all help will be greatly appreciated :)

edit 1:
some one asked for the full error messages so here it is
[image: error message]

edit 2:
ive changed the createLayer to createDynamicLayer and the stage now loads :)
But now i get a error for setting my flag to be unaffected by gravity through .setAllowGravity(false) any ideas?
error message below
[image: grav error message]

Comment: could you provide the whole error/warning message? are there other error Messages, because if `createLayer ` isn't a function, `addTilesetImage` shouldn't be a function either. btw.: the trailing comma in functions calls like here `this.skyMap.createLayer('stems', this.tileset,)`, might work but is very bad practice and can lead to problems. One final question with exact version of phaser are you using 3.55.2 or older ?

Comment: the errors seem abit strange, since the error's _...(reading 'setText')..._ should not happen, if the code you posted is the same as in your applocation. If so, the only thing I can think is, that the data / files are somehow cached. **btw.:** did you check your phaser version? is it higher than 3.50.0?

Comment: **You are using an old version of phaser** Upgrade to a new versions and "all" problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other Error message, the problem could be you are using a **older Version of phaser**:

> Prior to v3.50.0 this method was called `createDynamicLayer`. *( [mentioned in the official documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html#createLayer__anchor) )*

**Solution:** Just update the `phaser.js` to atleast  `v3.50.0` Version, best would be the latest [stable Version](https://phaser.io/download/stable) *(currently **v3.55.2**)*.